# Hibernate readonly collection mapping

Tags: hibernate, orm, collections, hibernate-mapping, readonly-collection

I'm taking the following *many-to-many* mapping example from this [Hibernate Mapping Cheat Sheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/HibernateMappingCheatSheet.html):

```
<class name="Foo" table="foo">
  ...
  <set role="bars" table="foo_bar">
     <key column="foo_id"/>
     <many-to-many column="bar_id" class="Bar"/>
  </set>
</class>

<class name="Bar" table="bar">
  ...
  <set role="foos" table="foo_bar" readonly="true">
    <key column="bar_id"/>
    <many-to-many column="foo_id" class="Foo"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

A Foo has several `bars`, and a Bar has several `foos`.
Because Bar.foos is declared *readonly*, I guess that I just need this simple method:

```
public class Foo {
    public void addBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bars.add(bar);
    }
}
```

And **not**:

```
public class Foo {
    public void addBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bars.add(bar);
        bar.foos.add(foo); // readonly
    }
}
```

My guess is that I cannot ensure consistency that way (adding back the `Foo` to the `Bar`). Does Hibernate guarantee this consistency itself, by automatically updating `Bar.foos` whenever I add a `Foo.bars`, or is the `Bar.foos` collection static once initialized?

For example if I do this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();

bar.getFoos().size(); // expected to return 0
foo.addBar(bar);
bar.getFoos().size(); // expected to return 1
```

Will the return values of `size()` be the ones I expect?

I could not find the relevant documentation yet, so a pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/. If you open the DTD file at http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd, you'll discover that there is no role nor readonly attribute in a set. Your documentation is probably obsolete. Use the reference documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the references should be marked `inverse="true"`, not readonly.

The inverse part is not stored by NH. But, of course, you get consistency problems in memory when you work with that objects.

Take a look at the reference documentation, [Bidirectional associations with join tables,  Many-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-join-m2m)